# htaccess exception from RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA]

Tags: .htaccess, typo3

in typo3 htacces finish all redirection by RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA],
but I need create PromoCode foldier with php aplication and own index.php work under adres www.domainname.com/PromoCode. So i need to add exception into htacces, but not sure how...

```
RewriteRule ^rss\/([^\.]+).xml$ fileadmin/rss/$1.xml    [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^fileadmin\/(.*)$  fileadmin/$1    [QSA,L]

# SPECIAL
RewriteRule ^ua-ru/links807835.php fileadmin/links807835.php [QSA,L]


# PAGING
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?!order\/.*)\/order\/([^-]+)-([^\/]+)(.*)$    $1$4?pg_order=$2&pg_by=$3   [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?!order\/.*)\/order\/([^\/]+)(.*)$    $1$3?pg_order=$2    [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?!page\/.*)\/page\/([^\/]+)(.*)$  $1$3?pg_page=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?!size\/.*)\/size\/([^\/]+)(.*)$  $1$3?pg_size=$2 [QSA,L]

# FAQ
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?!faq\/.*)\/faq\/([^\/]+)(.*)$    $1$3?faq=$2 [QSA,L]

# GALLERY
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?!gallery\/.*)\/gallery\/([^\/]+)(.*)$    $1$3?gallery=$2 [QSA,L]

# ARTICLE
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?!article\/.*)\/article\/([^\/]+)(.*)$    $1$3?article=$2 [QSA,L]

# PRODUCT
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?!product\/.*)\/product\/([^\/]+)(.*)$    $1$3?product=$2 [QSA,L]

# EVENT
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?!event\/.*)\/event\/([^\/]+)(.*)$    $1$3?event=$2   [QSA,L]

# MATERIAL
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?!material\/.*)\/material\/([^\/]+)(.*)$  $1$3?material=$2    [QSA,L]

# CATEGORY
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?!category\/.*)\/category([^\/]+)([^\/]+)(.*)$    $1$3?category=$2    [QSA,L]

# LANGUAGE
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)\/$    $1?id=$1    [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)$ $1?id=$1 [QSA]
#RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)[\/]{0,1}(.*)$    $2?lang=$1  [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)[\/]{0,1}(.*)$  ?lang=$1 [QSA]

# PAGE
RewriteRule ^[\/]{0,1}([^\/]+)[\/]([^\/]+)[\/]([^\/]+)[\/]{0,1}(.*)$    ?id=$3&pid1=$2&pid2=$1  [QSA]
RewriteRule ^[\/]{0,1}([^\/]+)[\/]([^\/]+)[\/]{0,1}(.*)$    ?id=$2&pid1=$1  [QSA]
RewriteRule ^[\/]{0,1}([^\/]+)[\/]{0,1}(.*)$    ?id=$1  [QSA]

# FINISH
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/PromoCode/
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the `RewriteRule .* index.php` line, add this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/promocode/
```

make the `/promocode/` folder whatever the foldername is that you want to make an exception for.

Comment: @user3223050 it would have helped had you posted your entire htaccess file from the start. If it's that complicated, try creating a new htaccess file inside the `PromoCode` folder with **only** the line: `RewriteEngine On`.